# How to get list of vector c++

Tags: c++, vector

I have this function on a class like this, this is using `#include <dirent.h>` library

int the header `directory.h`

```
class Directory {
 public:
  explicit Directory(std::string path);
  ~DirectoryReader();
  std::vector<std::string> daftarFiles;
  std::vector<std::string> files() const;

 private:
  DIR *dir_;
};
```

in the class name `directory.cpp`

```
std::vector<std::string> DirectoryReader::files() const{
     std::vector<std::string> files;
     struct dirent *ent;
     while ((ent = readdir(dir_)) != NULL) {
            if (ent->d_type == DT_REG) {  // regular file
                   files.push_back(ent->d_name);
            }
     }

     return files; 
}
```

How to get call data from that vector in my main program? I would like to do like `.size()` and calling value inside the vector. Because when I passing `.push_back()` function to public vector called `daftarFiles`, it will return error

Comment: Not really sure what you're asking. That function expects you to return a copy of a vector. Anyone calling it would be able to capture and use that copy. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Suggestion: `#include <filesystem>` and you'll be able to write standard C++ code for interating over directories instead of this Posix-only version.

Comment: Please include a snippet of code of your main program with what you're trying to do. Your explanation is not clear enough.

Comment: Work on a [mcve] and show what you're trying to do and where you get the error. Make sure to copy/paste the entire error as-is into the question as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply call the function in your main and assign it:

```
std::vector<std::string> daftarFiles = files();
```

(you can also use [auto](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/auto)). You can now access the contents via `daftarFiles`, e.g. `f.size()`, etc.